# Platform configuration for projects in VS 2010

Tags: c#, configuration, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions, solution

I have a third-party project type in Visual Studio which for some reason only supports the **.NET** Platform configuration for the build, for all other (standard C#) projects in the solution I only have **AnyCPU**.  Unfortunately, ever since upgrading to VS 2010 it produces following error when built :

> Error 39  The OutputPath property is
>   not set for project
>   'ReferencedBusinessProject.csproj'. 
>   Please check to make sure that you
>   have specified a valid combination of
>   Configuration and Platform for this
>   project.  Configuration='Debug' 
>   Platform='.NET'.  This error may also
>   appear if some other project is trying
>   to follow a project-to-project
>   reference to this project, this
>   project has been unloaded or is not
>   included in the solution, and the
>   referencing project does not build
>   using the same or an equivalent
>   Configuration or
>   Platform. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets  483 10  CustomTypeProject

It's pretty much descriptive in what is missing but I haven't found any way to fix it so far. Do you have any idea how this can be resolved or what can be the problem ?

Comment: adding/editing OutputPath in the .csproj file doesn't solve the problem?

Comment: That would probably solve the (part of the) problem, if I would put an unconditional OutputPath there (for all the configurations). The problem is however that the configuration is not recognized and as a result all conditioned properties ignored.

Comment: Have you tried create a 'new solution' with empty project placeholders which ressemble what you really have. Then look / edit / modify the real .csproj in accordance to the 'placeholder'.csproj files? you are probably missing large sections in the .csproj file which specify different configurations for different builds. I'm no MSBUILD expert, but it's just some XML after all.

Comment: Not sure if it can help: you can create new configurations in build->configuration menu. (x86 & x64). If not all projects are "any cpu" the batch builder (msbuild) won't be able to match them properly..

Answer (score 3):

The .Net Platform must have been created for the project before you received it for transparency reasons check the project settings and if it's building any cpu then fix the project configuration. (Standards are AnyCPU, x86, x64, win32) etc...

I would suggest you right click on the ".sln" file and in configuration manager set the properties of what you would like build when you call a platform. I.e.

This sample is best served with a configuration called "Mixed Platforms"

```
csproj1    platform=AnyCPU configuration=debug  build checkbox (checked)
csproj2    platform=.net   configuration=debug  build checkbox (checked)
```

This will allow you to build with msbuild
The call would be

```
msbuild my.sln /p:configuration="Debug" /p:platform="Mixed Platforms"
```

Both projects will build.